# How to I loop this loop until 1 man is the output

Tags: assembly, arm

I have code that produces the output below. How would I loop the code again to produce an output as shown below.

```
  verses    DEFW    4
    temp    DEFW    0
    text    DEFB    " men went to mow a meadow\nWent to mow a meadow\n",0
    text1   DEFB    " men, ",0
    text2   DEFB    "1 man and his dog, spot\nWent to a meadow",0



        ALIGN

    main    LDR R0,verses   
        SWI 4

        ADR R0,text
        SWI 3

        LDR R0,verses
        SWI 4

        ADR R0,text1
        SWI 3

        LDR R0,verses



    loop SUB R0,R0,#1
        SWI 4
        STR R0,verses
        ADR R0,text1
        SWI 3
        LDR R0,verses
        CMP R0,#2
        BNE loop

        ADR R0,text2
        SWI 3

        SWI 2
```

this is the current output

[image]

I would like to achieve this put don't know how.

[image]

Comment: **Add the architecture.** I suspect MIPS but I'm not sure.

Comment: This looks like the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429403/using-a-nested-loop-in-assembly

Comment: Add an enclosing loop. Line 1 of each verse depends on the loop variable. Line 2 is always the same. Line 3 needs a nested loop down to 2 men, followed by "1 man [etc]" every time. Line 4 is always the same. Notice the tricky bit in line 1 whether it's `man` or `men` output. Stick to `men` for now, and solve that bit last.

Comment: make the '1 man'-part a separate string. And, use some other register than r0 for the loop counter. Now you are using it to everything, and it would be overwritten. A pseudocode might be helpful.